# HTML/CSS - Change layout based on available elements

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning

I would like to change my web page layout based on what elements are available.

In some cases the **green** element is present and in other cases it is not.
I would like the layout to change as seen in the image below (without using absolute positioning).

Is this possible?

**Image:**
[Layout change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1og1e.png)

Thanks!

EDIT:

- I have only used HTML and CSS
- I got it to work by using position absolute on the blue element, but then it did not affect the width of the red element.
- It does not matter whether the green element isn't in the DOM or if it is display: none

Comment: Are you using `bootstrap` so far?

Comment: No, I am not. But if bootstrap helps, I would like to see the solution :)

Comment: You will need to add some javascript to do this. Check if green exist on the page, then apply the class you want from your grid system to red.

Comment: what you have tried so far @MattiasBregnballe

Comment: will the green div be present in dom or will it be display:none?

Comment: I have updated the OP

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using flexbox. Here's an example:

Code:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#red {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 80%;
  flex: 1 0 80%;
  /* this set a base width of 80%, but can grow */
}

#green {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
}

#blue {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="green"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

You can set `display: none` to the green div and you will have what you want to achieve

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8a8689p/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the :empty pseudo selector to select elements that contain either nothing or only an HTML comment, if the green element still exists and is empty

in css:

```css
div:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

If the div doesn't exist you have to use JavaScript to check if it exists

```js
if(document.getElementById('id_of_element'))
{
    
}
```

Comment: Cool! I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000
}

.red {
  position: relative;
  background: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.green {
  float: left;
  background: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.blue {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="red">Red</div>
  <div class="green">Green</div>
  <div class="blue">Blue</div>
</div>
```